# How to correctly shutdown all threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have 8 threads which each execute loops similar to this in their run method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < someVar; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < someOtherVar; j++) {
       if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
           return;
       }
       // another loop and some calculations here
   }
}
```

I start the Threads like this:

```
 executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);

 // generate the threads and run them
 for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
    MyClass cls = new MyClass(i);
    executor.execute(cls);
 }
```

Now I need to be able to pretty much instantly kill my threads, that's why I added the if statement above and use at another point `executor.shutdownNow()`. But it just isn't working fast enough. Some calculations might take a few seconds before they finish and the next iteration starts.

Is there any other reliable way to pretty much immediately shutdown threads?

Comment: Why isn't it fast enough?

Comment: Use a [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).

Comment: i'd think the first thing to do is measure how long the tasks go between checks for interruption, and try to reduce that interval by introducing more checks. have you tried that?

Comment: also if these tasks are waiting or sleeping or listening on a socket or anything you should mention that. more code would help.

Answer (score 1):

You need an interrupt operation that calls into the thread and stops the current execution. Here's some documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html

> An *interrupt* is an indication to a thread that it should stop what it is doing and do something else. It's up to the programmer to decide exactly how a thread responds to an interrupt, but it is very common for the thread to terminate.

Comment: ? The executor shutdownnow method is doing the interrupting. I don't see how this helps the OP, it seems to me he's already aware of this.

Comment: Handling an interrupted exception is very different from polling in a loop on each cycle whether the thread has a pending interrupt. I think the way this is implemented is that if you don't catch an interrupted exception, then the thread catches it and sets the flag. If you catch it, you can react much faster.

Comment: something has to trigger the interruptedexception. You're guessing he's sleeping and eating the InterruptedException and going on until the next check? since the OP is doing calculations it seemed unlikely the tasks were sleeping. but it wouldn't be the first time somebody asked a vague question and then it turned out something wacky was going on.

Comment: The master thread causes the InterruptedException. The thread receives and stops calculation in the processor immediately and uses the newly declared interrupt handler. Without the Catch for InterruptedException, another default hander is just setting the "interrupted" flag for review later and then returning to execution. This is very low level for Java and much more familiar to a C programmer.

Comment: Then why would the compiler require you to add a try-catch when calling `Thread.sleep();` if there would be some kind of default handler?

Comment: The thread can only respond 'immediately', in a language-friendly manner, to the interrupt request if it has already entered the JVM, (and thence the OS), on a blocking call - the call can be signaled to return early with an error and so raise a Java exception.  If it is running code on another core, it can stop itself by reading the flag periodically.  The only other way to stop such a thread is for the OS to rip execution from it with an actual, real hardware interrupt of the core that runs it, (as happens when the process is terminated). That is extremely language-unfriendly:)